# number pyramid using while loop for python

Tags: python, while-loop, nested

I'm supposed to have an output that looks like this:

```
          1
        2 1
      3 2 1
    4 3 2 1
  5 4 3 2 1
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

I am using this code:

```
 outer = 1
 while outer <=6:
     inner = 1
     while inner <= outer:
         print(inner, end=" ")
         inner = inner + 1
     print(" ")
     outer = outer + 1
```

but it's not doing what it's supposed to do. It looks like this instead:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use `string.join()`.

```
def triangle(levels):
    for i in range(1,levels + 1):
      print(' '*2*(levels - i) + ' '.join(str(j + 1) for j in reversed(range(i))))

triangle(6)
```

makes

```
          1
        2 1
      3 2 1
    4 3 2 1
  5 4 3 2 1
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking your code, there were only 2 issues:
1. You were printing in increasing order. So if you subtract the outer from inner, it would print the numbers in decreasing order
2. The padding varies from one line to the next, so add the padding in the outer loop. This is how your code would look with the 2 revisions:

```
outer = 1
while outer <=6:
     inner = 1
     print (" " * 2 *(6 - outer), end="")
     while inner <= outer:
         print(outer - inner + 1, end=" ")
         inner = inner + 1
     print(" ")
     outer = outer + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `while` solution:

```
outer = 1
while outer <= 6:
    inner = outer
    pos = 6       # create a position variable and start from 6 since you are printing backward
    while pos >= 1:
        if pos > inner:         # print white space if pos is larger than the diagonal
            print(" ", end=" ")
            pos = pos - 1
        else:
            print(inner, end = " ")  # Start to print number when pos is smaller than inner
            inner = inner - 1
            pos = pos - 1
    print(" ")
    outer = outer + 1

          1  
        2 1  
      3 2 1  
    4 3 2 1  
  5 4 3 2 1  
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: ah thanks a lot for the explanations too. it really helped me a lot ^_^